# Unity Raycast2D doesn't work with TilemapColliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

My project uses multiple 2D tilemaps to make an illusion of a 3D world. I need to get access to the tilemap in a script by clicking on one of its tiles.

The method I wrote is working with box colliders well, but it just ignores any 2D Tilemap colliders.

```
private void MoveToTile()
{
Vector3 mousePosition = _playerInput.Player.MousePosition.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        mousePosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePosition, Vector3.forward);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Tilemap clickedTilemap = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        }
}
```

I tried to use Composite colliders instead, but it doesn't work too. Also i tried switch on/off 'is trigger' parameter and change body type and 'is simulated' in Rigidbody2D.

Comment: you're starting at the world and moving away.. you want to go from camera, to world..

Comment: `Physics2D.Raycast` works in 2D space .. usually using `Physics2D.Raycast(someWorldPoint, Vector2.zero)` should work as expected

Answer (score 2):

Using [Physics2D.OverlapPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapPoint.html), instead of Raycast helped me out

```
private void GetMovePoint()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = _playerInput.Player.MousePosition.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    mousePosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

    Collider2D currentCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePosition);

    if (currentCollider != null && currentCollider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Tilemap currentTilemap))
    {
        Debug.Log(currentCollider.gameObject.name);
        Vector3Int targetPosition = currentTilemap.WorldToCell(mousePosition);
    }
}
```

You can learn more about it here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-does-the-composite-collider-2d-component-not-detect-raycasts.1079966/

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer is in the review queue due to being your first. Unfortunately, I can't release it as the explanation for why this works and the sample in the question doesn't is just a URL. As the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) states, you should provide context for links - always quoting the most relevant part. Thank you for contributing to the site! I hope this helps you find more success on the site in the future. Please don't be discouraged from further posts - the information is good, just needs framing and protecting from external resource loss.

Comment: @IAmJersh I can't really follow your concerns ... OP literally included a complete code snippet showcasing the fixed usage - the URL is the original source which is nice to include as there is further information and discussion, which OP literally also stated right before the URL: `You can learn more about it here`

Comment: @derHugo, the issue I found with the answer is that while the snippet is complete, there's no explanation as to *why* this works. If people looking for answers to similar problems with raycasting and tilemaps are limited to only seeing alternative code that works, they do not actually learn anything. If the url breaks (as they are wont to do), we lose all explanation. Under the `How do I write a good answer?` heading of the faq, one requirement is `Always quote the most relevant part of an important link`. This is an answer, but it is not yet a good answer based on the site guidelines.